# How to divide an array to two dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below.

```
$arr=array('0_1','0_3','1_2',1_1','4_1');
```

can i divide it into

```
$arr[0][1]='0_1';
$arr[0][3]='0_3';
```

...
Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried so far post your attempts too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $items = explode('_', $item);
    $newArray[$items[0]][$items[1]] = $item;
}
var_dump($newArray);
exit();
```

This should do the trick. You should have a look at the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this without `foreach` loop. :->

```
$arr = array('0_1','0_3','1_2','1_1','4_1');
$result = [];
array_walk($arr,function($v,$k)use (&$result){
    $data = explode("_",$v);
    $result[$data[0]][$data[1]] = $v;
});
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. but It seem the first solution is more readable and simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrv = array('0_1','0_3','1_2','1_1','4_1');
$newArray = [];
array_walk($arrv,function($value,$key){
    global $newArray;
    $indexArray = explode("_",$value);
    $newArray[$indexArray[0]][$indexArray[1]] = $value;
});
var_dump($newArray);
```